# Access Storyboard from embedded project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I have got two projects **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**, where **ProjectA** is the main project and **ProjectB** is embedded into **ProjectA**.

When I try to access the storyboard of **ProjectB** from **ProjectA**, I get error the storyboard doesn't exist, understandably the storyboard from **ProjectB** is not added into the target of **ProjectA**.

How would I reference the storyboard of the embedded project?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to save "Storyboard B" into Project A. Simply drag the storyboard into the Projact A's folder. Make sure to set in the App's overview the right storyboard as main.

---

If this don't work, try to save the storyboard within the Finder, copy the storyboard from Project B and paste it into Project A>base.lproj

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the answer is not realistic, by adding storyboard to ProjectA will add into target then I will need to drag ViewControllers as well to get functionalities, the ProjectB has more than 30 ViewControllers and each has dependency with external libraries, it not possible to flirt with that..

Comment: Ok than you can try to copy the Project B folder into Project A this may helps